# Map not loading into HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a map that I want to load into the HTML page, the file for the map is located into the app folder but does not load. Here is the codes for the place for inserting the map

```
<!-- Contact section start -->
    <div id="contact" class="contact">
        <div class="section ">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="title">
                    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                    <p>Duis mollis placerat quam, eget laoreet tellus tempor eu. Quisque dapibus in purus in dignissim.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="map-wrapper">
                <div class="map-canvas" id="map-canvas">Loading map...</div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span5 contact-form centered">
                            <h3>Say Hello</h3>
                            <div id="successSend" class="alert alert-success invisible">
                                <strong>Well done!</strong>Your message has been sent.</div>
                            <div id="errorSend" class="alert alert-error invisible">There was an error.</div>
                            <form id="contact-form" action="php/mail.php">
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input class="span12" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="* Your name..." />
                                        <div class="error left-align" id="err-name">Please enter name.</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input class="span12" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="* Your email..." />
                                        <div class="error left-align" id="err-email">Please enter valid email adress.</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <textarea class="span12" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="* Comments..."></textarea>
                                        <div class="error left-align" id="err-comment">Please enter your comment.</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <button id="send-mail" class="message-btn">Send message</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="span9 center contact-info">
                    <p style="color:black;">123 Fifth Avenue, 12th,Belgrade,SRB 11000</p>
                    <p class="info-mail">ourstudio@somemail.com</p>
                    <p style="color:black;">+11 234 567 890</p>
                    <p style="color:black;">+11 286 543 850</p>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Contact section edn -->
```

and here is the js file that has all the codes necessary to load the map.

```
    //Initialize google map for contact setion with your location.

function initializeMap() {

var lat = '44.8164056'; //Set your latitude.
var lon = '20.46090424'; //Set your longitude.

var centerLon = lon - 0.0105;

var myOptions = {
    scrollwheel: false,
    draggable: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, centerLon),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

//Bind map to elemet with id map-canvas
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

infowindow.open(map, marker);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);
```

}

I saw others having similar problems but they fixed it by typing optimized:false in the marker area but for me it is still not working.

Comment: Maybe it's a dumb question but did you include the gmap api before your initializeMap code ? Moreover I don't see any call to initializeMap(), do you have something like this ? google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);

Comment: Yea I did add the script for initializeMap at the bottom of my page with the other codes like this
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;callback=initializeMap"></script>
and google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initializeMap); is put under the js code but I forgot to paste it here . @AntoineGuillien

Comment: Is there somewhere online we can see your code ? Does it throw any errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues :

1. You call `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);` *inside* `initializeMap()` itself - then naturally the map is never initialized.
2. You need to set some dimensions on `#map-canvas`; even if issue #1 not were the case the map would never be shown either.

When these two issues is corrected it works -> **http://jsfiddle.net/1fdzz7gv/**

The fiddle has the exact same code as in OP, except `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);` is placed outside `initializeMap()` and `#map-canvas` has been given some dimensions

```
#map-canvas {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it did help a lot! I already defined the map-canvas in my css file just dint realise that google.maps.... was placed inside initializeMap();